# com.microsoft.projectoxford.vision.rest.visionserviceexception: unable to resolve host in android v1.0

Tags: android, api, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using Microsoft Vision and Face api for extracting data from image and detect face from image. I am using the following link as reference:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Vision/Android.

It was working fine for me but suddenly it stopped working and was throwing following error:

> "com.microsoft.projectoxford.vision.rest.visionserviceexception:
>   unable to resolve host in android"

I tried to change api roots

> https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0
>   https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr/

and I also regenerate the api key but it is still not working. 
Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: using `compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:vision:1.0.394'`?

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya recently i am using this version

Comment: Is the full URL something like `https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze`?

Comment: Jon i am also used full url but not working

Comment: it's still not working,

Comment: Can you add more details about your implementation of this call?